# Use typeahead.js with bloodhound.md and an external json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I try to use [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) with [bloodhound.md](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) and an external json data source. I thought I would follow the documentation and the examples provided on github as precisely as possible. However, I fail to achieve the desired dropdown.

Can you tell me, what I am doing wrong?

**[edit]**
I moved the whole code (js and json) to jsbin, so there shouldn't be any problems with cross domain calls.

Find the example code here:
http://jsbin.com/vajamixubo/1/edit?html,js,output

I would also be grateful for hints how to effectively debug typeahead.js calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your example, you are missing a reference to the Typeahead and Bloodhound library. Add the following to your HTML:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Now the typeahead control will work but it will show suggestion results as "undefined" when you search for them. This is because your display key is incorrect, it should be:

```
displayKey: 'genre'
```

The working example can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/vujafuwonu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Finally, to easily debug javascript in the browser add:

```
debugger;
```

to your code (e.g. try putting this at the start of your javascript). If you have the browser console open, script execution will stop at these debug statements.

Alternatively, in your example open the browser console, click on the "Sources" tab, and then navigate to "(no domain)/vajamixubo.js". This is the javascript that gets executed by jsbin and you can place breakpoints in here.

Comment: thank you! I think it's easier to try this at home (where the json is on the same domain as the js) instead of trying to get it working with jsonp. So I will try this out later this day.

Comment: @speendo No problem. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: `engine.initialize()` definitely was a step forward. I also think it should be `return { genre: genre.name};`. However, I still didn't succeed make it working. Is there another mistake? I also didn't manage to update the jsfiddle so it works cross domain (I don't need that in my project, however it would maybe make debugging easier).

Comment: I moved the example code to jsbin, so there shouldn't be a problem with cross domain calls. Find it here: http://jsbin.com/vajamixubo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi! You would definetely deserve more upvotes for pointing out even my stupid errors (like forgetting to link the typeahead-library). However, my JSON seems to meet the standards (JSON validators don't indicate an error). There was another bug: I forgot `displayKey: 'genre',`. Would you like to point out this final bug in your answer (you can also link to the working example here: http://jsbin.com/vujafuwonu/1/edit?html,js,output), so I can accept your answer?

Comment: @speendo Lol, we got there in the end! I missed the display key discrepancy. I'd still advise enclosing the JSON keys within quotes, as this is what the standard recommends, but I suppose if it works then all is fine.

Comment: Thank you once more! I didn't quite get what you mean with "enclosing the JSON keys within quotes" as I didn't find an unquoted JSON key in my example (which is by the way generated by django). I only saw the int values unquoted, which, however is covered by the JSON standard. Which key did you find unquoted?

Comment: I just check the JSON again and I was wrong. Your JSON is fine and the keys are enclosed within quotes. The extension I was using in Chrome was hiding them. Doh! Glad I could help and this exercise helps me reinforce my knowledge too :)